# Hibernate <mapping> tag attributes

Tags: hibernate

I am new to Hibernate, and I have a question about the Hibernate configuration file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`).  I noticed the following tag:

```
<mapping resource="xyz.xml">
```

I know the `resource` attribute is to read thr xml file.  But what about `file`, `class`, `jar`, `package` attributes?  Where can I get full documentation about these configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the online document for configuration details:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html

If you want to map a class then you have to use:

```
<mapping class="com.package.EntityName"/>
```

**Update:**

[Configuration.addFile(File)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addFile%28java.io.File%29)

```
- Read mappings from a particular XML file
```

The configuration to read from a file will be like :

```
<mapping file="path_to_your_xml_file"/>
```

If you use `resource` then hibernate will look into class-path but for `file` you need to give complete path.

[Configuration.addJar(JarFile)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addJar%28java.io.File%29)

```
Read all mappings from a jar file

Assumes that any file named *.hbm.xml is a mapping document.
```

So in this case the JAR file in class-path contains all the hbm mapping files.

The configuration will be like:

```
<mapping jar="path_to_your_jar_file"/>
```

[Configuration.addPackage(packageName)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addPackage%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Read package-level metadata.
```

This `addPackage` is used for different purpose, you can refer to these links to understand when to use the `package`:

[Hibernate Annotation Extensions, sction 2.4.3.2. Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property)

[AnnotationConfiguration().addPackage(packageName)](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=980723)

Comment: I have seen the file, jar, package attributes for <mapping> tag in dtd file. if there in no configuration why they have given them???

Answer (score 0):

you can configure class and package in the xml file like:

package:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="your.domain">
```

class:

```
<class name="classname">
```

documentation
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html

Comment: Here I am asking in hibernate.cfg.xml,not in entity mapping